# performKeyEquivalent called twice for some key strokes

Tags: cocoa

Pressing "Command +" results in two -performKeyEquivalent calls. Here is a stack trace snippet for the first call:

```
1   AppKit                              0x00007fff903da2f9 -[NSView _performKeyEquivalent:conditionally:] + 41
2   AppKit                              0x00007fff903da442 -[NSView performKeyEquivalent:] + 166
3   AppKit                              0x00007fff903da2f9 -[NSView _performKeyEquivalent:conditionally:] + 41
4   AppKit                              0x00007fff903da259 -[NSWindow performKeyEquivalent:] + 64
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff903da044 -[NSApplication _handleKeyEquivalent:] + 462
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff90297173 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 4480
```

And for the second call:

```
1   AppKit                              0x00007fff903da2f9 -[NSView _performKeyEquivalent:conditionally:] + 41
2   AppKit                              0x00007fff903da442 -[NSView performKeyEquivalent:] + 166
3   AppKit                              0x00007fff903da2f9 -[NSView _performKeyEquivalent:conditionally:] + 41
4   AppKit                              0x00007fff903da259 -[NSWindow performKeyEquivalent:] + 64
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff903da044 -[NSApplication _handleKeyEquivalent:] + 462
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff900e3927 -[NSApplication _handleSpecialAlternateKeyEquivalent:] + 656
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff9029718e -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 4507
```

As you can see, the second -performKeyEquivalent call is initiated by -[NSApplication _handleSpecialAlternateKeyEquivalent:]. So, could anyone tell me what is so special about "Command +" key stroke that it warrants not one, but two -performKeyEquivalent calls, and how do I filter out the second call?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is that the first call returned `NO`, so AppKit tries again with a slightly different event. Are you overriding `performKeyEquivalent:`? Are you returning `NO` the first time?

---

Notes from [Cocoa Event Handling Guide: Handling Key Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html):

> **NSWindow subclasses are discouraged from overriding performKeyEquivalent:.**
>
> Note: Beginning with OS X v10.5, if a key equivalent is not recognized, NSWindow sends it as an NSKeyDown event to the first responder. This behavior enables custom key-binding entries with Command-key modifiers. In addition, NSApplication sends a Control-key event to the key window via performKeyEquivalent: before sending it as an NSKeyDown event through the responder chain. This behavior allows more reliable use of Control-key events as menu key equivalents.

Comment: Yes, I do return 'NO' both times. This I can't change (well, I can, of course, but don't want to for some technical reasons). Everything is fine when there is only one call to -performKeyEquivalent per key stroke (which is the case for the most key strokes). It is the second call that messes things up. So far, Cmd + is the only key stroke I'm aware of that produces such effect. I'd like to know why Cocoa handles it differently.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old thread but I keep running into it when I do searches and recently saw some old code related to this.

This looks like a hack on Apple's part. Some sort of Zoom In or Magnify feature is often given the shortcut Cmd +. On US keyboards (and many others) the user expects it to work when they press Cmd = since the plus symbol is also on that key. So Apple sends Cmd = first and then if that doesn't get a response sends Cmd +. I haven't tested this in detail but it only seems to do this when = and + share the same key and + is the shifted character. For example, it won't do this if you press Cmd = on the numeric keypad. Which makes it difficult to filter out, you can't assume Cmd = will be followed by a Cmd + that you can discard.

This also happens with Cmd+Period. Apple first sends Cmd+Period and then Cmd+Escape. Based on the source code I'm looking at these are the only two cases where this happens.

Update: the second event is not equal to `NSApp.currentEvent` since it is not sent through the normal dispatch mechanism. That seems to be one way of filtering it out.

Comment: While the question is no longer relevant to my job, this answer is an interesting piece of history. Thanks for sharing it!